# Using the same parameter for a react package but in different files

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing two react packages, one called `main` and one called `serverHelper` In main, there are several 'pages' (like, `editUser.tsx`, `createUser.tsx` etc), each occasionally importing serverHelper.ts.

serverHelper has a bunch of functions like `getUser()`, `updateUser()`, etc. which are essentially fetch functions that hits a server.

My question is: I'd like to pass in the request URL, which is different when I'm running dev and prod. The URL is extracted from a local config file (this part I've set up already.) How can I set up/import serverHelper so that I only have to pass in the request URL to serverHelper once, and not in the many files. I've looked into Contexts and Hooks but can't quite wrap my head around how those would work in this case...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than passing the request URL around, can't you just use `window.location`?  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: @user2740650 I'm confused at how that would help, but maybe I'm not interpreting your comment correctly. Window.location is the current page address. The serverHelper his hitting a request URL to a different endpoint not on the same server

Comment: Oh, I'd assumed it was running on the same server.  One option is to have a small config js file that they all import, with just a setter and getter for base url (or a global variable if you prefer).  I don't think it needs to be any fancier than that if I'm interpreting correctly.